# How to overcome the OutOfMemory situation when using multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, out-of-memory, task

I'm having an application in C# that can run either as a Windows Service or as a Console Application.

This application maintains a singleton queue of jobs (any access to it is mutual excluded) and at any time only N maximum jobs can be run simultaneously by using Tasks (from .NET). The main thread of the application does not wait the tasks to complete.

A timer is triggered repeatedly after some interval and tries to handle a new job. The jobs load and handle files with big file sizes (500MB - 1GB). When two or more jobs run at the same time (when tasks run simultaneously) an OutOfMemoryException (OOM) appears.

Why this happens?

Is it because all Tasks use the same VM of the process which is limited to 2GB on 32bit architectures and 4GB on 64bit?

Tasks are implemented with threads right?

How can I solve this problem?

I could use Multi-process architecture so each child process could have its own VM of (2GB/4GB) so no overflow could happen so easily (since I have no files bigger than 2GB). But this would mean that I have to refactoring the whole application to use child processes instead of tasks. Can I share data, such as the singleton job queue in different processes?

All configuration happens with Spring.NET

Is there any way I can solve this problem by using Tasks in the same application?

Is it possible to increase the VM of a process?

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Do you read the entire file into memory? If so then please consider changing it because in many scenarios this is a complete waste of memory and a streaming approach can work as well.

Comment: We use XML files and load the files with XDocument.Load() by using FileInfo and XmlReader. We analyze data so it is necessary to load all data.

Comment: That creates an entire DOM tree, which consumes even more memory than the file. If you don't actually *need* that tree then using XmlReader would be better.

Comment: When you say streaming approach can you please give me an example?

Comment: That applies to normal reading of files, i.e. not using File.ReadAllText but instead use a FileStream to read parts of it. For XML files XML readers provide *"fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data."* [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have used an XmlReader with this way: XDocument.Load(xmlReader)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62332/discussion-between-efstathios-chatzikyriakidis-and-dirk).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll solve the problem by refactoring the system with Multi-process architecture.